# Is this map dense in $S^1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Consider the map $\Bbb Z[\frac{1}{2}]/\Bbb Z\to S^1$ whereby $f(x)=e^{2xi\pi}$.  Is this set dense in the unit circle?

I believe this is dense in the unit circle because every pair of points is bisected by another.  Is this theorem true, and its proof correct?

Comment: Regarding the title: $\mathbb C^\times$ is the whole complex plane without the origin, not just the unit circle, so the (image of) the map is certainly not dense in it,

Comment: @Wojowu ok thanks for the heads up. What is normal to call the unit circle?

Comment: The most common notation (used in one of the answers) is $S^1$. Similarly, $S^{n-1}$ denotes the unit sphere in $n$-dimensional space.

Comment: Ah ok. I changed it to $\Bbb C:\lvert x\rvert=1$ is that also ok?

Comment: A better way would be to use the [set-builder notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation): $\{x\in\mathbb C:|x|=1\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Another approach. The image of $f$ is a subgroup of the circle which is not finite, so it is dense.

Let $H$ be a subgroup of $S^1$ and $p:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow S^1$ the canonical projection, $p^{-1}(H)$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$, it is dense or discrete.

Suppose that $p^{-1}(H)$ is discrete and generated by $a>0$, the subgroup $L$ of $\mathbb{R}$ generated by $a$ and $2\pi$ is dense or discrete, if it is discrete, its equivalent to the fact that it is generated by ${2\pi\over n}$ and $p(L)=H$ is finite. If it is dense, $p(L)=H$ is dense.

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_of_Real_Numbers_is_Discrete_or_Dense

Comment: Thanks. Are you saying every subgroup of the circle which is not finite, is dense? It seems amazing we can have such a theorem and not show that $\pi$ is normal.

Comment: @RobertFrost Normality is _much_ more difficult than density. Indeed, the proof that every subgroup that isn't finite is dense is pretty easy: by the pigeonhole principle, for any $\epsilon$ there are two members $a,b$ of the subgroup which are less than $\epsilon$ away from each other; then $ab^{-1}$ is less than $\epsilon$ away from the identity, so the powers $(ab^{-1})^n$ for $0\leq n\leq \lfloor\epsilon^{-1}\rfloor$ cover $S^1$ with maximum gap less than $\epsilon$...

Answer (score 1):

Basically, yes. In greater generality, the map $e^{2\pi i x}:\Bbb R\to S^1$ is a [quotient map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(topology)#Quotient_map), and the image of a dense set by a quotient map is always dense.